# The right workflow - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It kind of a complicated question...

I have a server side application (standalone). In general this server gets client connection and create a logic layer to each client.

the problem I have is with the data.
the logic layer depend on a project, each project has a some common logic flows and lots of unique flows.

I want to create a core logic class that all other projects can extend them- this is just the introduction....

**The Data**

all projects using this data table (a sample to single common table)

```
   ItemID     ItemName     State
```

so I can create a `DbContext`

```
 public class CoreContext : DbContext  {
       public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
 }   

 public class Item {
      public int ItemID { get; set; }
      public string ItemName { get; set; }
      public int State { get; set; }
}
```

now, the changes in the data is when creating new and unique project. exmaple project A can also have this table (ItemsAttribute):

```
   ItemID     AttributeName     AttributeValue
```

This table can be only used in project A and not in project B . and project B add another table (ItemsUsers) :

```
   ItemID     UserID      Permission
```

I tried extending the `CoreContext` class like so

```
 public class ProjectBContext : CoreContext  {
       public DbSet<ItemsUsers> ItemsUsers { get; set; }
 }
```

or extend the model classes like so

```
public partial class Item {
       public List<ItemAttributes> Attributes {get;set;}
}

public class ItemAttributes {
       public string AttributeName { get; set; }
       public string AttributeValue { get; set; }
}
```

the CoreContext and ProjectBContext each one of them has it's own project and DLL file

I Dont know what is better practice - and I'm puzzled with few solutions:

1. create one big context entity framework class that can covers all my projects - the problem is : hard to maintain and alot of migration problems
2. create a separated context to each project  and not extend the `CoreContext` - problem : not solving the add fields to a model
3. leave the EF solution and go back to old ADO.NET - problem: it's not 1995..

any suggestion or feedback will help... thanks!

Comment: Option 4 - Look at Polyglot and Document storage.  Sounds like you don't adhere to a schema.  Here is a really good video I watched about NoSQL - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI_g07C_Q5I.

Comment: @Mr.B - thanks for the comment - I wanted to user NoSQL solution, but I have a lot of relationship tables. but I consider your solution

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!